# Create column identifying speaker roles

Tags: r, dplyr

A seemingly simple question: I have a character vector of `Speaker` Ids. I know that the `Speaker` value which occurs most of the time is the "Storyteller", whereas the others are "Recipient". How can I create a column `Role` that identifies both "Storyteller" and "Recipient"?

```
df <- data.frame(
           Speaker = c("A","B","A","A","C","A")
         )
```

All I know so far is how to count the character values:

```
df %>%
    group_by(Speaker) %>%
    count()
```

Desired result:

```
  Speaker    Role
1       A    Storyteller
2       B    Recipient
3       A    Storyteller
4       A    Storyteller
5       C    Recipient
6       A    Storyteller
```

Comment: All I know in advance is 'that the Speaker value which occurs most of the time is the "Storyteller"'. So the way forward will be by using `max` or somethign similar

Comment: As in A told story to B, A told story to C?

Comment: It's all the same story: A is storyteller, B and C are recipients

Comment: another way of doing this is using `max(table(df))`

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are more elegant ways, but a base R approach would be:

```
df$Role <- ifelse(df$Speaker %in% names(which.max(table(df$Speaker))), 
                  "Speaker", "Recipient")
```

Output:

```
  Speaker      Role
1       A   Speaker
2       B Recipient
3       A   Speaker
4       A   Speaker
5       C Recipient
6       A   Speaker
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `add_count` combined with an `ifelse` statement:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  add_count(Speaker) %>%
  mutate(Role = ifelse(n == max(n), "Storyteller", "Recipient"), .keep="unused")

Speaker        Role
1       A Storyteller
2       B   Recipient
3       A Storyteller
4       A Storyteller
5       C   Recipient
6       A Storyteller
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of doing it:

```
s <- slice_max(count(df, Speaker), n)$Speaker

df$Role <- ifelse(df$Speaker == s, "Storyteller", "Recipient")
```

Comment: No I don't know in advance who is the storyteller and who is not.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann i think this is what you had in mind

Comment: though not as beautiful as answers to come :')

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `min`, as `max` will guide you to `C`.

```
df$role = ifelse(df$Speaker == min(df$Speaker), 'Storyteller', 'Recipient')
df
  Speaker        role
1       A Storyteller
2       B   Recipient
3       A Storyteller
4       A Storyteller
5       C   Recipient
6       A Storyteller
```

BTW what FLIR were you using for your pupil size data?

Comment: This doesnt work if the most frequent speaker is not "A". This is just another way of saying `df$Speaker == "A"` since `min` will simply return the minimum of the characters - try `min(c("A", "B", "B", "C"))`

Comment: Agreed, and were it not Speaker A, then the data would be different above.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by that. The OP stated, "All I know in advance is 'that the Speaker value which occurs most of the time is the "Storyteller"'. " There was no implication that it would always be "A"

Comment: All of which your solution addresses. And I like better than mine...

Answer (score 0):

Without using `min`/`max`, in case of a draw label all.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  add_count(Speaker) %>% 
  mutate(Role = c("Recipient", "Storyteller")[(n == n[order(n) == n()]) + 1], 
         n = NULL)
  Speaker        Role
1       A Storyteller
2       B   Recipient
3       A Storyteller
4       A Storyteller
5       C   Recipient
6       A Storyteller
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do,

```
with(df, c('Recipient', 'Storyteller')[(Speaker == names(which.max(table(Speaker)))) + 1L])
# [1] "Storyteller" "Recipient"   "Storyteller" "Storyteller" "Recipient"   "Storyteller"
```

which is faster than `ifelse`.